# How to save file in folder using AngularJS service and Laravel Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, file-upload, save

I am not getting how can I send file form service to laravel controller and store it in a folder.

Here is view and controller (Angularjs Front end)
**View**

```
<html>

 <head>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>

  <body ng-app = "myApp">

  <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
     <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
     </form>
  </div>

 ** controller**
  <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = {'file' : file}
           var file = {
            'file' : file
           }
            console.log(uploadUrl, fd)
            $http.post("http://myipaddress/practice/upload/blog/public/index.php/uploadavtar",uploadUrl, fd)
            .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            });
        }
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);

  </script>
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests; 
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
public function uploadavtar(Request $request){


     $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
     Input::file('file')->move(
       '192.168.2.68/practice/upload/public/files/uploads/', $filename
     );

      $fullPath = 'myipaddress/practice/upload' . $filename;

     return  $fullPath ;

}
 }
```

I checcked the above larave controller through postman its working fine only problem is its not storing the file. And if I do same from submit button its showing error of

```
'Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object
'
```

How to solve this both issues.
1. Sending file form service to laravel controller 
2. storing it in defined path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error saying that there is no file in the request(POST)

```
    if( $request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
        Input::file('file')->move('192.168.2.68/practice/upload/public/files/uploads/', $filename);
        $fullPath = 'myipaddress/practice/upload' . $filename;

        return  $fullPath ;
    }
    else
    {
        //file from post does not exist
    }
```

EDIT

You got the paramaters wrong in your ajax

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

            $http.post("http://myipaddress/practice/upload/blog/public/index.php/uploadavtar", fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
         })
         .success(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
         })
         .error(function(){
            console.log("error");
         });
        }
     }]);
```

the first paramater is for the link, second is the form data, and last is the settings

Comment: But now I m not getting how can I send the file from angularhs $http request to laravel controller. COntroller function working fine I check through postmant. @lukegkennjordan

Comment: what is use of uploadurl? @lukeglennjordan